# no color change after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, background-color

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m49gswh2/5/show/) in which after every second I am changing the background color to a different color.

I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the Javascript code below as present in the fiddle so that there is no color change after 10 seconds. The JS code which I am using is:

```js
var i = 0;

function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green", "red", "yellow", "white", "pink", "purple", "orange"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
myVar = setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
</div>
```

Comment: Put that Interval in an if statement if time < 10 seconds and increment the interval every time

Comment: Keep track of the color changes with a variable that increments in `change`. Then, clear the interval with `clearInterval` when that variable is 10 in `change`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
var i = 0;
var doc = document.getElementById("background");
var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green", "red", "yellow", "white", "pink", "purple", "orange"];
function change() {
    if (i < 9) {
        doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        i = (i + 1);
    } else {
        doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        clearInterval(myVar);
   }
}

myVar = setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
</div>
```

Comment: I would only add that you should clear the interval after reaching ten iterations.

Comment: Haha, he's right. I never noticed that `i` is never incremented!

Comment: @Austen Keene Although its working but I can't see the last color i.e. orange.

Comment: You could change to: `doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i % color.length];       i = i + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

clear the interval after 10 seconds with timeout

Try this:

```js
var i = 0;

function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green", "red", "yellow", "white", "pink", "purple", "orange"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
myVar = setInterval(change, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}, 10000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

#background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
</div>
```

Comment: See - much better. And make sure you create a [mcve] so copy the HTML and style too next time

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(myVar)
}, 10000)
```

Comment: Come on. Reposting Amit's with the duration corrected? He could have done that too

Comment: If you're referring to the submission that I think you are, that was not the only mistake. The initial answer used setInterval(). Either way, it's not a contest, I'm just trying to help people. Cheers.